# Automatically identify the dependent package for LaTeX symbol command

Tags: math-mode, symbols, packages, dependencies

Given a command like `\kreuz`, is it possible to create an application that will smartly recognise and import its dependent package `wasysym`, to enable its rendering out on a webpage?

The aim is to have such application render any symbols in the CTAN Comprehensive List, given the corresponding command.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  One problem is that some symbols have representations in multiple packages.  For example, AMS and MnSymbol both have a `\nsubseteq`.

Comment: it isn't clear what you intend here, in what way does knowing the package help put the symbol _on a web page_ ?

Comment: In the Index of http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf is a list of most symbols which link you back to the section with the relevant package

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm currently receiving a bunch of LaTeX symbol commands which I'm trying to render unto the webpage, using either MathJax or KaTeX. However, this fails, which is what has raised my question. (Entering in the above symbol does NOT render out) --- is there an alternative method I can employ for this?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'm not sure I understand... do you mean that symbols of those packages have that prefix?

Comment: No, my point is that you wish to specify the symbol and have your program know what package to use to get it.  Let's say the symbol you wish to use is `\nsubseteq`.  There are [at least] two packages that provide a representation of a symbol with that name.  The representations from the two packages will be slightly different.  How should it know which variant you prefer?

Comment: In addition, there are other packages that replace a whole slew of symbols all at once.  While there are clever ways of importing just the particular symbol you want without overwriting all the rest of the symbols you don't want overwritten, the means to do so is itself package dependent, and by no means standardized.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks for your response. I suppose if I can get to that phase, I wouldn't mind either returning a list of such packages....and render it out using each of them, for the user to decide which they prefer. How difficult do you reckon it is to implement? Any signpost in the right direction of resources to help me get started for that would be most appreciated.

Comment: Please see one such approach given in my answer.  I would think it is more work than it is worth, but you may decide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach is both easy and hard (and more trouble than it is worth, in my opinion).  Hard because the user has to laboriously catalog the package associated with each symbol in a style file.  But easy because each new symbol requires only a single line added to the `AddSymbol.sty` file, for example, `\def\AddSymbolVdash{\RequirePackage{amssymb}}`.

Then, in the preamble of your document, in addition to `\usepackage{AddSymbol}`, one needs to add `\AddSymbol{\Vdash}` in order to load the proper package, in this case `amssymb`.

In the MWE below, I actually create the stencil for `AddSymbol.sty` as part of a `filecontents` environment.  It has error checking, if the symbol has not yet been defined.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,etoolbox}

\begin{filecontents*}{AddSymbol.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{AddSymbol} [2016/04/13 V1.0]

\newcommand\AddSymbol[1]{%
  \ifcsname AddSymbol#1\endcsname%
    \csname AddSymbol#1\endcsname\else%
    \AtBeginDocument{Symbol: #1 unknown to AddSymbol\par}\fi%
}
\def\AddSymbolkreuz{\RequirePackage{wasysym}}
\def\AddSymbolLbag{\RequirePackage{stmaryrd}}
%
% CONTINUED LIST OF PACKAGES FOR EACH KNOWN SYMBOL
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{AddSymbol}
\AddSymbol{kreuz}
\AddSymbol{foo}
\AddSymbol{Lbag}
\begin{document}
$ A \kreuz B \,\Lbag C$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Steven. (sorry for the late reply). I see what you mean about questioning its worth. Your input has been much appreciated